# AFNetworking works for iOS8, but doesn't work for iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, app-transport-security

What might be wrong if my class responsible for connection works when I run on simulator with `iOS8`, but it is not going to work with simulator on `iOS9`. What is the reason?

Comment: Maybe [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)?

Comment: You are right. It is working...:) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading a non-https URL using `AFNetworking`, you need to add an **App Transport Security** override in your *info.plist* file like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>
```

You can also add overrides for specific domains, which is a better approach. More info here:

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/